# Dynamically passing selectInput values from UI to Server code in R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, diagrammer

The process_map() function in the server in the R shiny script creates the diagram image as below. My requirement is that there are two attributes "FUN" and "units" that are part of the performance() function. They have standard four values each that are available in the ui code below under PickerInput ID's Case4 and Case5. Currently, I am hard coding the value to create the map, can you help me to use the id's in the server code and make it dynamic such that when I select the value in the PickerInput, the formula fetches the value directly. Thanks and please help.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(bupaR)
library(processmapR)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(edeaR)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DiagrammeR)
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Diagram Plot",titleWidth = 290),
dashboardSidebar(width = 0),
dashboardBody(
tabsetPanel(type = "tab",
            tabPanel("Overview", value = 1,

                     box(
                       column(1, 
                              dropdown(
                                pickerInput(inputId = "resources", 
                                            label = "", 
                                            choices = c("Throughput Time"), 
                                            choicesOpt = list(icon = c("fa fa-bars", 
                                                                       "fa fa-bars", 
                                                                       "fa fa-safari")), 
                                            options = list(`icon-base` = "")),
                                circle = FALSE, status = "primary", icon = icon("list", lib = "glyphicon"), width = "300px"
                              ),

                              conditionalPanel(
                                condition = "input.resources == 'Throughput Time' ",


                                tags$br(),
                                tags$br(),
                                tags$br(),
                                dropdown(
                                  pickerInput(inputId = "Case4", 
                                              label = "Select the Process Time Summary Unit", 
                                              choices = c("min","max","mean","median"), options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE), 
                                              multiple = F),
                                  circle = FALSE, status = "primary", icon = icon("eye-close", lib = "glyphicon"), width = "300px"
                                ),
                                tags$br(),
                                tags$br(),
                                tags$br(),
                                dropdown(
                                  pickerInput(inputId = "Case5", 
                                              label = "Select the Process Time Unit", 
                                              choices = c("mins","hours","days","weeks"), options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE), 
                                              multiple = F, selected  = "days"),
                                  circle = FALSE, status = "primary", icon = icon("eye-close", lib = "glyphicon"), width = "300px"
                                ))),
                       title = "Process Map", 
                       status = "primary",height = "575", width = "500",
                       solidHeader = T,
                       column(10,grVizOutput("State")),
                       align = "left")


                     ),

            id= "tabselected"
            )))
  server <- function(input, output) { 
  output$State <- renderDiagrammeR(
  {

    if(input$resources == "Throughput Time")
      patients %>% process_map(performance(FUN = mean,units = "days"))
    else
    return()
    })}
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Diagram Image]

Answer (score 1):

test this:

```
output$State <- renderDiagrammeR({

      if(input$resources == "Throughput Time")
      {
        if(input$Case4=="mean"){
        patients %>% process_map(performance(FUN = mean,units = input$Case5))}
      else if(input$case4=="min"){
        patients %>% process_map(performance(FUN = min,units = input$Case5))
      }else if(input$case4=="max"){
        patients %>% process_map(performance(FUN = max ,units = input$Case5))
      }else{
        patients %>% process_map(performance(FUN = median ,units = input$Case5))
      }

        }else
        return()
  })
```

or you can use this:

```
patients %>% 
process_map(performance(FUN = eval(parse(text=input$Case4)) ,units = input$Case5))
```

enjoy;)

here is a sample:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
selectInput(inputId = "func", label = "Choose The Function", choices = c("mean", "sum", "median"))
,
textOutput("text")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  main_data <- reactive({
    data.frame(a= rnorm(100), b=rnorm(100) )
  })

  output$text <- renderText({
    df <- main_data()

   apply(df,2, FUN =  eval(parse(text=input$func)) )
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I am getting an error "argument is of length zero", please help me here, also why can't I make the FUN variable dynamic?

Comment: run it without shiny and test it if you have correctly computed everything (for example: patients). you can use a switch function or this way, I only know these two ways

Comment: your solution is completely correct, but my point is to reduce the usage of if's and make it as crisp and dynamic I can using shiny input ID's, is it running fine in your system?

Comment: you can test the switch function(above link) to see if it change the performance of your code

Comment: Performance is not my issue here, I want to use the input ID's in the process map function somehow?

Comment: We have used one of them, but It's getting interesting, cause I have been doing this type of tasks in this way for a year. 
I am out of office now, but  tonight (local time) i will brief you on my solution

Comment: I appreciate your assistance, at your convenience please!

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: thanks for the effort, but I somehow still am getting an error here, have you checked the code from your side?.

Comment: I added a simple Example of what you need, take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `do.call` to call a function from its name, see the example below. You can add arguments by adding them in the list in the `do.call` function, e.g. `list(x,units=input$Case5)`.

---

[image]

---

```
library(shiny)

x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

ui <- fluidPage(
 selectInput('select','Select Function: ', choices=c('mean','max','min','median')),
 textOutput('text')
)

server <- function(input,output)
{
  output$text <- renderText({
    result = do.call(input$select, list(x))
    paste0('The ', input$select, ' of [', paste(x,collapse=', '),'] is ', result)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the help, regarding your "paste0" command, if you can replace it and test this command  patients %>% process_map(performance(FUN = result ,units = "days")). Also you need renderDiagrammeR and grvizOutput to call the diagram, I need help here. Thanks.